# I get an error in basic configuration with socket.io in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have an error in the console saying io is not defined.
This is mi code in server side:

```
const express = require('express')
const { Server: HttpServer } = require('http')
const { Server: IOServer } = require('socket.io')

const app = express()

const httpServer = new HttpServer(app)
const io = new IOServer(httpServer)

app.use(express.static('public'));

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('Nuevo cliente conectado');

    socket.emit('mi mensaje', 'este es mi mensaje desde el servidor')
})

const PORT = 8070

const server = httpServer.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`server running`);
})

server.on('error', error => console.log(`Error en servidor ${error}`))
```

and this is mi code in the client side(here is where i get the error in console):

```
// Cliente
const socket = io.connect();

socket.on('mi mensaje', (data) => {
    alert(data)
})
```

I'm doing the basic configuration and i cant make it work and i don't know why

Comment: Are you loading or defining Socket.io on the client? It's not just there automatically.

Comment: If you're using express, you don't _also_ need the `http` module. But, if you're using express, _definitely_ use [express-ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ws) instead of socket.io, so you can simply add `app.ws(....)` the same way you add `app.get` and `app.post` etc.